# Encountering "10005 TXN_AUTH_FAILED" error in GridDB during client request execution

Tags: error-handling, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I am currently facing an issue while executing a client request in GridDB, and I'm receiving the error code "10005 TXN_AUTH_FAILED." This error occurs.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

To resolve this issue, I have verified the username and password to ensure their correctness.

Despite these countermeasures, the problem persists. I'm seeking assistance to understand if there are other potential causes for this error in the context of GridDB or if there are additional steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The GridDB default user/pass combo is `admin/admin`. Have you tried this? Or did you change it and forget? As far as I know, this error will only come up if you have tried an incorrect user or password.

Other than that, i'd say just delete the cluster and start over if you truly can't connect with correct credentials